# Can't convert Alamofire request to Moya

Tags: swift, alamofire, moya

I have written an Alamofire request like below and get successful result.

```
let urlString = "https://dev.thebeats.app/api/authorization/send_signup_email?lang=en"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

AF.request(url, method: .post,
                   parameters: ["email": "a@b.com"],
                   encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                   headers: ["Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
                   interceptor: nil, requestModifier: nil)
            .response { result in
                print(String(decoding: result.data!, as: UTF8.self))
            }
```

Here is the response

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "success": true,
    "message": "Email send successfully",
    "body": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlkIjo1Nywic3ViIjo1NywibmFtZSI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNjU1OTc5NTczLCJleHAiOjE2NTYwNjU5NzN9.331-g9WCEy6OIVkdm4UnxOx3BnuEx1fNy59shiYBgvQ"
    }
}
```

I have tried to write this request with Moya but always getting 404 error. Here is the code.

```
extension AuthenticationService: TargetType {
    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "https://dev.thebeats.app/api")!
    }
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .registration:
            return "/authorization/send_signup_email?lang=en"
        }
    }
    
    var method: Moya.Method {
        switch self {
        case .registration:
            return .post
        }
    }
    
    var task: Task {
        switch self {
        case .registration(let email):
            var params: [String: Any] = [:]
                        params["email"] = "a@b.com"
            return .requestParameters(parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        }
    }
    
    var headers: [String : String]? {
        switch self {
        case .registration:
            return ["Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        }
    }
    
    var validationType: ValidationType {
        return .successCodes
    }
}
```

Here is the response using `Moya`

```
{
  "message": "Controller class Api could not be found.",
  "url": "/api/authorization/send_signup_email%3Flang=en",
  "code": 404,
  "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php",
  "line": 340
}
```

Please help me to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing `%3F` in the URL, I'd say that's the strange part. Your request is strange. You pass some parameter using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` inside the URL (`lang`), and some inside the body (`email`)? Can't you send them both in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make it **post** , so this should be

```
    case .registration:
        return "/authorization/send_signup_email"
```

With

```
params["email"] = "a@b.com"
params["lang"] = "en"
```